# Why aren't the C-supplied integer types good enough for basically any project?

Tags: c, types, integer

I'm much more of a sysadmin than a programmer. But I do spend an inordinate amount of time grovelling through programmers' code trying to figure out what went wrong. And a disturbing amount of *that* time is spent dealing with problems when the programmer expected one definition of __u_ll_int32_t or whatever (yes, I know that's not real), but either expected the file defining that type to be somewhere other than it is, or (and this is far worse but thankfully rare) expected the semantics of that definition to be something other than it is.

As I understand C, it deliberately doesn't make width definitions for integer types (and that this is a Good Thing), but instead gives the programmer `char`, `short`, `int`, `long`, and `long long`, in all their signed and unsigned glory, with defined minima which the implementation (hopefully) meets. Furthermore, it gives the programmer various macros that the implementation must provide to tell you things like the width of a char, the largest unsigned long, etc. And yet the first thing any non-trivial C project seems to do is either import or invent another set of types that give them explicitly 8, 16, 32, and 64 bit integers. This means that as the sysadmin, I have to have those definition files in a place the programmer expects (that is, after all, my job), but then not all of the semantics of all those definitions are the same (this wheel has been re-invented many times) and there's no non-ad-hoc way that I know of to satisfy all of my users' needs here. (I've resorted at times to making a <bits/types_for_ralph.h>, which I know makes puppies cry every time I do it.)

What does trying to define the bit-width of numbers explicitly (in a language that specifically doesn't want to do that) gain the programmer that makes it worth all this configuration management headache? Why isn't knowing the defined minima and the platform-provided MAX/MIN macros enough to do what C programmers want to do? Why would you want to take a language whose main virtue is that it's portable across arbitrarily-bitted platforms and then typedef yourself into specific bit widths?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When a C or C++ programmer (hereinafter addressed in second-person) is choosing the size of an integer variable, it's usually in one of the following circumstances:

- You know (at least roughly) the valid range for the variable, based on the real-world value it represents.  For example,

  - `numPassengersOnPlane` in an airline reservation system should accommodate the [largest](http://planes.findthebest.com/l/242/Airbus-A380-800) supported airplane, so needs at least 10 bits.  (Round up to 16.)
  - `numPeopleInState` in a US Census tabulating program needs to accommodate the [most populous state](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/California) (currently about 38 million), so needs at least 26 bits.  (Round up to 32.)

In this case, you want the semantics of `int_leastN_t` from `<stdint.h>`.  It's common for programmers to use the exact-width `intN_t` here, when technically they shouldn't; however, 8/16/32/64-bit machines are so overwhelmingly dominant today that the distinction is merely academic.

You *could* use the standard types and rely on constraints like “`int` must be at least 16 bits”, but a drawback of this is that there's no standard *maximum* size for the integer types.  If `int` happens to be 32 bits when you only really needed 16, then you've unnecessarily doubled the size of your data.  In many cases (see below), this isn't a problem, but if you have an array of *millions* of numbers, then you'll get lots of page faults.

- Your numbers don't need to be that big, but for efficiency reasons, you want a fast, “native” data type instead of a small one that may require time wasted on bitmasking or zero/sign-extension.

This is the `int_fastN_t` types in `<stdint.h>`.  However, it's common to just use the built-in `int` here, which in the 16/32-bit days had the semantics of `int_fast16_t`.  It's not the native type on 64-bit systems, but it's usually good enough.

- The variable is an amount of memory, array index, or casted pointer, and thus needs a size that depends on the amount of addressable memory.

This corresponds to the typedefs `size_t`, `ptrdiff_t`, `intptr_t`, etc.  You *have* to use typedefs here because there is *no* built-in type that's guaranteed to be memory-sized.

- The variable is part of a structure that's serialized to a file using `fread`/`fwrite`, or called from a non-C language (Java, COBOL, etc.) that has its own fixed-width data types.

In these cases, you truly do need an exact-width type.

- You just haven't thought about the appropriate type, and use `int` out of habit.

Often, this works well enough.

---

So, in summary, all of the typedefs from `<stdint.h>` have their use cases.  However, the usefulness of the built-in types is limited due to:

- Lack of *maximum* sizes for these types.
- Lack of a native memsize type.
- The arbitrary choice between LP64 (on Unix-like systems) and LLP64 (on Windows) data models on 64-bit systems.

---

As for why there are so *many* redundant typedefs of fixed-width (`WORD`, `DWORD`, `__int64`, `gint64`, `FINT64`, etc.) and memsize (`INT_PTR`, `LPARAM`, `VPTRDIFF`, etc.) integer types, it's mainly because `<stdint.h>` came late in C's development, and people are still using older compilers that don't support it, so libraries need to define their own.  Same reason why C++ has so many string classes.

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes it is important. For example, most image file formats require an exact number of bits/bytes be used (or at least specified).

If you only wanted to share a file created by the same compiler on the same computer architecture, you would be correct (or at least things would work). But, in real life things like file specifications and network packets are created by a variety of computer architectures and compilers, so we have to care about the details in these case (at least).

Comment: OK, so your size_t is known at compiler compile time and your file access functions deal in increments of size_t's, right? Isn't the whole point of size_t that you *don't* have to ever get specific with how many bits you're using (other than the minimum widths required)?

Comment: Or am I being way too impractical and doctrinaire here?

Comment: The point of `size_t` is to store the result of the `sizeof` operator (or related quantities like array indices).  It has to be a typedef because there is no built-in type guaranteed to have the required semantics.

Answer (score 3):

The main reason the fundamental types can't be fixed is that a few machines don't use 8-bit bytes. Enough programmers don't care, or actively want *not* to be bothered with support for such beasts, that the majority of well-written code demands a specific number of bits wherever overflow would be a concern.

It's better to specify a required range than to use `int` or `long` directly, because asking for "relatively big" or "relatively small" is fairly meaningless. The point is to know what inputs the program can work with.

By the way, usually there's a compiler flag that will adjust the built-in types. See [`INT_TYPE_SIZE`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Type-Layout.html) for GCC. It might be cleaner to stick that into the makefile, than to specialize the whole system environment with new headers.

Answer (score 1):

If you want *portable* code, you want the code your write to function identically on all platforms.  If you have

```
 int i = 32767;
```

you can't say for certain what `i+1` will give you on all platforms.

This is not portable. Some compilers (on the same CPU architecture!) will give you -32768 and some will give you 32768. Some perverted ones will give you 0.  That's a pretty big difference. Granted if it overflows, this is Undefined Behavior, but you don't know it is UB unless you know exactly what the size of `int` is.

If you use the standard integer definitions (which is `<stdint.h>`, the ISO/IEC 9899:1999 standard), then you know the answer of `+1` will give exact answer.

```
  int16_t i = 32767;
  i+1 will overflow (and on most compilers, i will appear to be -32768)

  uint16_t j = 32767;
  j+1 gives 32768;

  int8_t i = 32767; // should be a warning but maybe not. most compilers will set i to -1
  i+1 gives 0; (//in this case, the addition didn't overflow

  uint8_t j = 32767; // should be a warning but maybe not. most compilers will set i to 255
  i+1 gives 0;

  int32_t i = 32767; 
  i+1 gives 32768;

  uint32_t j = 32767;
  i+1 gives 32768;
```

Comment: Conforming C code will never produce a negative result as the sum of two positive numbers. This only occurs under the auspices of Undefined Behavior. Overflow is still undefined even for `int16_t`.

Comment: @Potatoswatter - Yes you are correct, that integer overflows are "Undefined Behavior". But this is why you use known sized integers, rather that rely on the unknown sized integers, so you know when you code is conforming and when it isn't. For example, `int i=32767;i++;` Is that conforming or not?

Answer (score 0):

There are two opposing forces at play here:

- The need for C to adapt to any CPU architecture in a natural way.
- The need for data transferred to/from a program (network, disk, file, etc.) so that a program running on any architecture can correctly interpret it.

The "CPU matching" need has to do with inherent efficiency.  There is CPU quantity which is most easily handled as a single unit which all arithmetic operations easily and efficiently are performed on, and which results in the need for the fewest bits of instruction encoding.  That type is `int`.  It could be 16 bits, 18 bits*, 32 bits, 36 bits*, 64 bits, or even 128 bits on some machines.  (* These were some not-well-known machines from the 1960s and 1970s which may have never had a C compiler.)

Data transfer needs when transferring binary data require that record fields are the same size and alignment.  For this it is quite important to have control of data sizes.  There is also endianness and maybe binary data representations, like floating point representations.

A program which forces all integer operations to be 32 bit in the interests of size compatibility will work well on some CPU architectures, but not others (especially 16 bit, but also perhaps some 64-bit).

Using the CPU's native register size is preferable if all data interchange is done in a non-binary format, like XML or SQL (or any other ASCII encoding).

Comment: Those 18 and 36 bits machines certainly did have C. In fact they were some of the first.

Comment: @Potatoswatter:  I knew them to have odd languages like DIBOL and FOCAL; was C implemented on either a PDP-6 or PDP-10?

Comment: If you are using ASCII encoding for your numbers, you could really care less about the CPU's native register size. Converting decimal ASCII to binary is so expensive, worrying about register sizes is premature optimization.

Comment: `int` isn't the native size in typical 64-bit implementations.